# Add 5.30 hours in date Object

Tags: java, android, date, object

My date object out put is 1.05 pm, and it should be 6.35 pm. How to convert gmt to gmt 5.30.

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(new Date()); // sets calendar time/date=====> you can set your own date here
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5); // adds one hour
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // adds one Minute
cal.getTime(); // returns new date object, one hour in the future
```

**=======>** Setting time to calendar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/Calendarsetintfieldintvalue.htm)

Comment: But AM and PM is not changing if added in time.